# Need details on how aws data transfer costs are calculated using S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-transfer

We're making a social media app using amplify and are newbies to aws. The services we're using include s3, auth, hosting, analytics, api and lambda functions. We've already accrued significant data transfer usage and I'm guessing it's from repeatedly grabbing images from S3.

Does [`Storage.get()`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js) which generates a presigned URL count as "data transfer out"

Or does it only count when we actually view the file from the URL?

Is there a difference in data transfer between generating a URL and downloading the actual file with Storage.get?

Comment: Data Transfer only applies to data transferred to the Internet, such as users using your service. If you are "grabbing images from S3" from _within_ AWS, this should not be incurring Data Transfer charges. However, if your app is transferring them to users, then Data Transfer _will_ apply.

Comment: Thanks. By "grabbing images" I mean users are viewing the images on S3 using the app, so I guess that counts as data transfer.

Comment: That is correct. You can activate [Amazon S3 server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) if you want to obtain details of the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Major costs associated with S3 :***

1. **Storage cost** : charged per GB / month. ~ $0.03 / GB / month, charged hourly
2. **API cost for operation of files** : ~$0.005 / 10000 read requests, write requests are 10 times more expensive
3. **Data transfer outside of AWS region** : ~$0.02 / GB to different AWS region, ~$0.06 / GB to the internet.

Based on volume and region the actual prices differs a bit, but optimization techniques stay the same. I will use the above prices in following cost estimates

**Note** : Leverage [AWS Pricing Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/) as much as you can to save cost. It lets you estimate the cost for your architecture solution.

Answer (score 0):

Generating a URL does not cost anything because it's just a computational operation.

The price of S3 downloads can be computed using the [AWS Pricing Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/). Consider using a CDN such as CloudFront in front of S3. There are many benefits in using a CDN, one of which is pricing.

Comment: but suppose in react app, we assign that signed url to image component's source property, so that image is visible, so it is downloading the image right?